# How can I count number of entries in two other tables with MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three tables.

- Posts
- Images
- Votes

I want to be able to get all the data in the posts along with the the sum of the votes and the number of images associated with the post. I can get one or the other, but not both at once.

This code works for getting the score of a post

```sql
SELECT 
    posts.*, 
    COALESCE(SUM(votes.value), 0) as score
FROM posts 
    LEFT JOIN votes ON posts.post_id = votes.target_id
GROUP BY posts.post_id
```

and this code works for getting the number of images alongside posts

```sql
SELECT 
    posts.*, 
    COALESCE(COUNT(images.image_id), 0) as num_images
FROM posts 
    LEFT JOIN images ON posts.post_id = images.belongs_to_post
GROUP BY posts.post_id
```

but if I combine the two to get

```sql
SELECT 
    posts.*, 
    COALESCE(COUNT(images.image_id), 0) as num_images,
    COALESCE(SUM(votes.value), 0) as score
FROM posts 
    LEFT JOIN votes ON posts.post_id = votes.target_id
    LEFT JOIN images ON posts.post_id = images.belongs_to_post
GROUP BY posts.post_id
```

the `score` is multiplied by the number of images. How can I effectively stop this? Do I have to group by another column?

I'm using MySQL 5.7.31.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT p.*, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM images i
        WHERE p.post_id = i.belongs_to_post
       ) as num_images,
       (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(v.value), 0)
        FROM votes v
        WHERE p.post_id = v.target_id
       ) as score
FROM posts p;
```

With indexes on `images(belongs_to_post)` and `votes(target_id, value)`, this is probably much faster than any approach that uses aggregation in the outer query.